# Android startActivity - What is happening

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

What is happening under the hood? somehow this is passed down to the OS, and someshow the OS will find the right activity / activities, and launch it? Is there a service / lib running in Android handling this? I am trying to modified the OS to override the logic of startActivity across the board, is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I just can tell you that under the Application Framework (of which the class activity is part of) lay several c++ libraries which handles things as SQLite or Surface Manager and the Android Runtime, which ressembles from core libraries and the mobile JRE "Dalvik". Maybe you can use some buzzwords for further research

Comment: "I am trying to modified the OS to override the logic of startActivity across the board, is this possible?" - Are you talking of contributing to AOSP? Or from within an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point might be [ActivityManagerService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService)

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the Android source! Whenever I'm developing and I run into an issue I read through the source to discover what is happening under the hood; it's quite interesting! It's an insight into what's actually going on, and also very good guidelines for documentation and code formatting!

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when an app is first launched, [`startProcessLocked()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/com/android/server/am/ProcessRecord.java#ProcessRecord) in [ActivityManagerService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#ActivityManagerService) creates a new [`ProcessRecord`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/com/android/server/am/ProcessRecord.java#ProcessRecord) (if necessary) and then calls [`Process.start()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/Process.java#Process.start%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%29), which in turns builds the arguments for zygote and sends to zygote's socket using [`zygoteSendArgsAndGetResult()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/Process.java#Process.zygoteSendArgsAndGetResult%28java.util.ArrayList%29).  Of course there's more to it than that, for example if an app shares a uid, is isolated, etc. But that gives you the basic process.

Looking over the source is indeed a good way to understand what's going on. However, unless you're planning on modifying it, don't bother downloading AOSP, just use [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/). Easier to browse, search and everything is hyperlinked so it's easy to follow through to classes, find usages, derived methods, etc. If you download AOSP, you'll be stuck with grep, ack-grep if you're lucky and a text editor.  Also, you'll only have the one version you picked to checkout.  GrepCode has the code for almost every version since 1.5.

The linked text above will take you to the relevant source at GrepCode. Try it out! The only downside is that GrepCode doesn't include the native C++ layer.